# Push Notification to iOS successful but shows as 'failed'

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using APN module for sending Push Notifications to iOS. It all seems to be working good but I get always 'failed' as response result after sending the message where in fact I actually get the message on the phone (so it should not be 'failed').

Why is response showing as 'failed' and how to fix it?

```
var apn = require('apn');
var options = {
  token: {
    key: "keys/AuthKey_123.p8",
    keyId: "123",
    teamId: "teamA"
  },
  production: false
};

var json_message = {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "This is title",
            "body" : "This is body",
        }
    };

var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
var deviceToken = "device token";

var note = new apn.Notification();
note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge = 3;
note.sound = "ping.aiff";
note.alert = json_message.aps.alert.body;
note.payload = json_message;
note.topic = "com.test";

apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then( (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("\n*** Response: ***\n");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: Your `json_message` is missing one closing bracket.

Comment: That is true but even with extremely simple JSON (e.g. 1 key and 1 value) - same error show up (failed) when indeed is succeeded. So JSON is not the root cause in this case.. What it could be?

Comment: I'm sure thats not the issue. Probably you can check for an error object containing more details about the failure in the response. Also, did you try building a simple notification by only using the Convenience Setters?